# How to print label for UPS shipping service in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to implement UPS shipping service in my website, but I have no idea how will I print a label using their web service.
I am developing my project in `asp.net` with `C#`. If anyone implemented it before, please give me some sample code, it will be really great for me.

Comment: Are you doing this through your online account with UPS?  Or just as a  guest?  Are you making use of UPS's API?

Comment: Hello ,
i have an account with UPS. i am trying to us their webservice for this. but not sure how i will handle the shipping Lable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply point the user to a page with just the shipping label and directions on how to print from using browser's file --> print